# Broke screen, how to perform Nandroid/TWRP backup blindly?

Tags: twrp, broken-screen, nandroid

I have broken my HTC One (M8)'s display (and probably more) while attempting to replace the battery, and I'm selling it via eBay for parts. How do I attempt a full Nandroid backup with TWRP and then wipe the device securely, blindly? I have no screen whatsoever in the device, as the original one is broken. I had TWRP installed, as I mentioned. Is this possible via adb or fastboot? They seem to be working. I have S-Off and can get to the bootloader via commands.

Comment: See [Is there a way to do Nandroid backup directly to pc and then restore it directly from pc also?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/47975) However, if you've space in your phone to make a backup, then you can command TWRP to make backup in phone and then you can pull it through MTP or ADB in PC. For latter, see http://www.pocketables.com/2014/10/using-twrps-new-adb-interface.html

Comment: How would I command TWRP to make a backup in the phone without a screen?

Comment: Have patience. Follow the links. They will answer everything you need to know. The second link addresses your comment. You just have to boot into the TWRP. That's it. The rest can be done using adb.

Comment: Didn't see the 'for latter', thanks, will check it out. The majority of the first link's answers was using a pull of a img file, as I've never dealt with that before, I was a bit cautious if that would perform an entire backup.

Comment: It keeps saying that TWRP does not appear to be running, I'll try flashing a different version.

Comment: Pointer: Check our [broken-screen tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info), which a.o. deals with issues like that (I've just added that tag to your question).